# Why dont I have a windows update icon in the toolbar

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

I have windows update set up to download but not to install, I then normally click on the yellow shield, review the updates and install them.

Now when I shut down it tells me I can turn off and install updates... which indicates there are some updates downloaded but there is no yellow shield to review what they are.

How can I get the yellow shield back?

**Update 1**
I can confirm that I have the following selected;
"Download updates for me, but let me choose when to install them"
I also have "Hide Inactive Icons" unchecked

From the WindowsUpdate.log file , I have the following lines.

```
2009-09-02  21:58:27:343    3504    5a8 Shutdwn Install at shutdown: found updates to install
2009-09-02  22:00:40:953    1864    9c4 AU  AU found 1 updates for install at shutdown
```

I also have

```
2009-09-03  05:26:41:281    1864    1768    DnldMgr   * Update is not allowed to download due to regulation.
2009-09-03  05:26:41:281    1864    1768    DnldMgr Regulation: { a guid } - Update { a guid }  is "PerUpdate" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 3187 vs AcceptRate 0.
```

Googling ["Sequence 3187 vs AcceptRate 0."](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&hs=7AI&q=%22Sequence+3187+vs+AcceptRate+0%22&btnG=Search&meta=) doesnt give anything
But still no yellow shield.

**Update 2**
Googling a bit more has given these links, I havent had time to go through them yet but they look promising.

- [microsoft communites - no shield link](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windowsxp.general&tid=06397fb0-089e-4566-ad91-c379ce7a2e75&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1)
- [google groups - no shield link 2](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsupdate/msg/7d510d20cae32847)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - **"PerUpdate" regulated and can NOT download** - on a fresh install of XP SP3. It refuses to update automatically - apparently the only 'fix' is to run Windows Update in IE - hardly what you'd call 'automatic'!

Comment: as an update, a little while later the yellow shield came back again... not sure why it did.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your update preferences [got changed somehow](http://windowssecrets.com/2009/07/23/01-Learn-to-read-the-obscure-WindowsUpdate.log-file). Make sure your Automatic Updates setting is firmly on *Download updates for me, but let me choose when to install them*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might not see it because windows is not updating.

Another option is that you have hidden inactive icons in the task-bar.

To fix this:

- Turn on updates, as noted above
- Make sure that you have not checked "hide inactive icons" in the task-bar menu, via right click > Properties